# I have full control over file but tomcat 8.0 can't write on it

Tags: java, tomcat8

So, like i said on title. I have permissions over target file, but when running my app this exception is displayed

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: loggFile.txt (Acess denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at logger.Log.writeLine(Log.java:74)
at logger.Log.logInLog(Log.java:55)
at servlets.login.doGet(login.java:52)
at servlets.login.doPost(login.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to run a simple app, only to write on file and i had no problems. But when running app on server at tomcat8.0 i get that exception. I searched on web, but i only found answers relatively to file permissions (something that i already own it) or something related with security, that in this case i don't think that is the problem because the exception raised is about FileNotFound.

Thanks in advance! It's my first question, sorry for something you don't like (formatting, language, etc)   ;)

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo in the name of the file (loggFile.txt, double "g")?

Comment: You own the file, but does tomcat run under your user?

Comment: @tkausl how can i change these permissions?

Comment: @fluis how do you start Tomcat?

Comment: @PiotrK on eclipse, i have my server (tomcat) and my dynamic web project associated to the server. Click on index.jsp and run on server

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/371809/run-tomcat7-as-tomcat7-or-any-other-user ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a correct path? Remember that when you start tomcat all the files are relative to <tomcat_folder>/bin because this is the location of the start file "startup.sh"

Comment: @PiotrK i'm on windows.